# how to get BitmapImage in codebehind from the image tag in xaml in wpf/silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i dont have a problem with binding a bitmapimage to image tag in codebehind for eg.

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
imagetaginxaml.Source = image; // this will remove whatever image is currently on the image tag in xaml and attach the empty bitmapimage above
```

but i'm not able to get the image by doing the reverse, for example, i want to process the image that is currently on the image tag. i am not able to do this

```
BitmapImage image = imagetaginxaml.Source;
```

what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `WriteableBitmap` to make a copy of the image, and then using a `MemoryStream` to copy the original image into a copy?

```
// Create a WriteableBitmap from the Image control
WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(imagetaginxaml, null);

// Load the contents of a MemoryStream from the WritableBitmap
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
bmp.SaveJpeg(m, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

// Read from the stream into a new BitmapImage object
m.Position = 0;
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(m);

// do something with the new BitmapImage object
// (for example, load another image control)
anotherimagetaginxaml.Source = image;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, [`Image.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) is of type [`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx), there is no quarantee that it will be a [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx), it *may* be though. If the source is created by the XAML parser it will be a `BitmapFrameDecode` (which is an internal class). Anyway, the only save assignment is:

```
ImageSource source = img.Source;
```

otherwise you need to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx):

```
BitmapImage source = (BitmapImage)img.Source;
```

which will throw an exception if the `Source` is not of this type. So you can either [save-cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) or [try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx):

```
//(Possibly check for img.Source != null first)
BitmapImage source = img.Source as BitmapImage;
if (source != null)
{
     //If img.Source is not null the cast worked.
}
```

```
try
{
    BitmapImage source = (BitmapImage)img.Source;
    //If this line is reached it worked.
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //Cast failed
}
```

You could also check the type beforehand using `img.Source`[`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)`BitmapImage`.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'.    i get this error if i do BitmapImage source = (BitmapImage)img.Source;

Comment: @RemotePath: As i said, if you try a cast it will throw an exception if the Source is not of that type. `BitmapFrameDecode` was probably created by the XAML-parser, your cast is invalid. Read the article about casting that i linked to in my answer if you do not understand how this works.